# Django ForeignKey Required?

Tags: python, sql, django, entity-relationship, one-to-many

I have a three classes:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    email = models.EmailField()

class Exam(models.Model):
    place = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    taker = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    score = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 5, decimal_places = 2)
```

When I run this it complains that Student doesn't have a a ForeignKey to Exam. Why?

Comment: When you run what?  `manage.py syncdb`?  The only thing I see that looks "wrong" is that your `place` FK points to a class that you don't have listed here (you probably mean `Place` instead of `Location`)

Comment: @Danial: It complains in the admin when I try to add an exam.

Comment: @Danial: And here is the crazy thing: I have the admin setup to inline add exams with locations and don't have an error there.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your actual database is out of sync with your model.  You'll want to either drop and recreate your database using `manage.py syncdb` (easiest, but you will lose the data unless you use something like [fixtures to reload initial data](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/)) or use a migration tool like [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) to upgrade your existing database to reflect the new data model.

Comment: +1 because that's the first thing I tried and most likely the answer for anyone else searching. I just had a messed up `admin.py` file.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this on the manage.py shell:

```
from bar import models
l=models.Location("here")
s=models.Student(name="fred",email="foo@bar.com")
e = models.Exam(place=l,taker=s,score=99.9)
```

which I can do with no errors... Looks good to me..

Answer (score 0):

In the `admin.py` file I had `inlines = [StudentsInline]` setting. This tries to enforce adding multiple Students to one exam (thinking it's on the One side of a OneToMany relationship).